# Between GPS, compass heading and accelerometer, which consumes the most amount of battery?

Tags: iphone, gps, accelerometer, background-process, compass-geolocation

Does anyone know between GPS, compass heading and accelerometer which uses the most amount of battery (or how they compare relatively?)

I'm assuming somewhat naively it's:

accelerometer < compass heading < GPS

but I can't find anything to substantiate or refute my intuitions.

Clarification: I'm curious as to how it performs specifically on an iPhone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it really depends on the device. A GPS with an active antenna will consume the most power. Accelerometers and compass usually only draw milliamps when running. Generally your order is correct.

Specifically to the iPhone

1. GPS: 4mA (Assuming it runs on 3.3V. I cannot find the datasheet)
2. Compass: 1.2mA
3. Accelerometer: 0.25mA

Answer (score 2):

Your order is correct.

- MEMS accelerometers are based on measuring capacitors (this really do not have any consumption with an ADC).
- Magnetometers (compass) are based on measuring a ferro-resistive material, which have to be excited with large short-time current pulses + ADC. Therefore the consumption should be a little bit higher.
- GPS involves more than just reading an ADC, the signal has to be processed (generally by a FPGA or ASIC), therefore the consumption is higher.